# How can I call a variable function within a function with parameters?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to call a variable function within a function but it is not working as expected.

Here is my code:

```
$arg1 = "Beef";
$arg2 = "Potatoes";

$string1 = "Tomatoes";
$string2 = "Onions";

function func1 ($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1.' '.$arg2;
}

$var1 = "func1";

function func2($string1, $string2, $var1) {
    echo $string1." & ".$string2;
    $var1($arg1, $arg2);
}

func2($string1, $string2, $var1);
```

When I call `func2`, it only echoes "Tomatoes & Onions" Isnt `$arg1` and `$arg2` global? Why are they not seen inside the function `func2`? How can I call `$var1` inside `func2` along with its arguments?

Comment: use global $arg1,$arg2 inside func2

Comment: **Isnt $arg1 and $arg2 global?** Yes. By default, global variables aren't accessible inside functions.

Comment: `func2` does not include `func1` **inside** of it, nor the variables. You can either define them as global variables as shown in other comments, or, better, create a class/object with those functions and variables and work inside there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Func1 is expecting 2 parameters you're not passing to it, due to variable scope.

Change

```
function func2($string1, $string2, $var1) {
    echo $string1." & ".$string2;
    $var1($arg1, $arg2);
}
```

to

```
function func2($string1, $string2, $var1) {
    Global $arg1, $arg2;
    echo $string1." & ".$string2;
    $var1($arg1, $arg2);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: doesn't $string1and $arg1 have the same scope? Why do I need to declare global for $arg1?

Comment: Yes, string1 and arg1 have the same scope, and are both outside of the functions scope. However, with this line: func2($string1, $string2, $var1); you're adding String1 and String2 into func2's scope(via the parameters), while $arg1 is still outside of your functions scope. Unless it's passed through as a parameter or declared as a Global as I did above, it won't work.